# Determine the minimum and maximum angles, to the nearest tenth of a degree, that a pipe can make with the horizontal.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

For residential drains, a horizontal pipe needs to have a minimum slope of $1/4$ inch per foot and a maximum slope of $1/2$ inch per foot for waste to drain properly. This means that for every horizontal foot the pipe travels, it should drop between $1/4$ and $1/2$ inch.

This is the way I'm currently trying to solve this but I feel like I'm doing it completely wrong.

$$\tan x = opp / adj$$

$1/4$ inch by $12$

We have $\tan x= 0.25 / 12 = 0.020$, so $x = \tan^{-1} (0.020)= 1.1457^\circ$.

And if $\tan y = 0.50 / 12 = 0.041$, then $\tan^{-1} (0.04)= 2.3478^\circ$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\tan^{-1}(0,020)\approx 1.146^\circ$, so that's not where your mistake lies. Your mistake lies where you say $\frac {0.25}{12}=0.020$.

Firstly, we should use an "$\approx$" instead of an "$=$" (since this is not exact).

Secondly, approximations should always  be postponed  as long as possible. Why? Well, you already found out why. I would advice you make a habit of just leaving expressions like $0,25/12$ as they are. Just type `arctan (0.25/12)` into your  calculator and round off the result.